# How to get around unique id attribute value warning in aXe tool

Tags: angularjs, accessibility

I have a web page developed using angular. On the page I have a table which gets populated by controller in a loop, depending on the value of a particular cell, I am embedding a tooltip using ng-include for that cell. It might happen that the tooltip might get included on multiple rows in table in which case, aXe tool will complain about unique attribute id violation for that tooltip. Is there a suggested way to handle this case.

eg. inserting a simple example. Lets say I have a getValues() method that returns list  of values which can be string or number and a tooltip needs to be associated with the values to suggest they are either numbers or strings.

[1, "test", 2, "test2"]--> output would be like
1 (tooltip for number)
test (tooltip for string)
2 (tooltip for number)
test2 (tooltip for string)

```
<ul ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="value in values">
        {{value}} 
        <span ng-show="isNumber(value)" aria-labelledby="number-tooltip">
            <div ng-include="number-tooltip.ng">
            </div>
        </span>
        <span ng-show="isString(value)" aria-labelledby="string-tooltip">
            <div ng-include="string-tooltip.ng">
            </div>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the tooltip files

```
<div id="number-tooltip" role="tooltip">
    This is a number
</div>


<div id="string-tooltip" role="tooltip">
    This is a string
</div>
```

Comment: If you're asking how to fake out aXe so that you can have duplicate IDs, that's not possible. Having duplicate IDs is invalid html.  It won't pass an html5 checker (https://validator.w3.org/nu), and WCAG 4.1.1 specifically says IDs must be unique.  If you're asking how you can use angular so that unique IDs are generated, that's a much better question.  Can you clarify which one you're asking for?  It also might help to have a few more details or a code example.  Is it the tooltip element that has the ID that is repeated on multiple rows?

Comment: Thank you, edited the question with a simple code example. I am asking how are situations like this well handled for a11y purposes. In this case, getting the elements with duplicate ids that is, the tooltip with same id are repeated on multiple rows which are essentially the same elements.

Comment: The update helps, thanks.  So, why does the actual tooltip have to be repeated?  Can't you have the `id="number-tooltip"` block **once** in your code?  You are allowed to have multiple elements that all have their `aria-labelledby` pointing to the same ID.

Comment: I have the code only once, but since I am using ng-include to insert the tooltip file in multiple places the dom tree gets multiple instances of same html with the given id repeated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't append the loop iteration number to the id value? eg number-tooltip-0, number-tooltip-1, etc

Comment: I could do that. Just wanted to check if there were any other better ways to handle  duplicate ids. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must create unique ID's ... period.

No, Angular does not do that natively ... https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5145

No, you can not just append the loop index. Every time the loop refreshes, or is called elsewhere it will start with an index of 0 again. You must add another cumulative parameter to make sure its 100% unique ... generally this is accomplished by having a counter var that counts up every time the loop is opened. {{ counterVar + $index }}. There are Angular plugins to accomplish this, check npm.

**No, the question you are asking is not your biggest problem.** You are addressing a Accessibility compliance issue, without consideration to the actual **Usability of your app by humans** with screen readers and proper code architecture to avoid a snowballing anti-pattern.

Implementing the unique ID's for aria-labeledby is a box checked on your QA story or the automated tool you are validating your code with. It does not ensure that your product is usable by humans with screen readers.

The anti-pattern is ...

> I have the code only once, but since I am using ng-include to insert
>   the tooltip file in multiple places the dom tree gets multiple
>   instances of same html with the given id repeated. – Anu Oct 5 at
>   23:10

If I understand you correctly you are saying that you only have one
file per tooltip, but you are injecting it over and over for each
instance where the tooltip is used.

The screen reader is going to read everything. Meaning you have to manage the state of every element using aria-hidden attribute. Which means you are going to have to code more things. You are going to have to consider backwards compatibility (possibly leverage display:none instead of aria-hidden) and more.

Please read: https://accessibility.athena-ict.com/aria/examples/tooltip.shtml

This link is a walk through of what you need to build to have a Usable tool tip for screen readers.

The anti-pattern you are using in my opinion is injecting the tooltip component html over and over again. Even the guide I linked does it, but it’s old. This is not how apps are built today, especially Angular style frameworks.

These frameworks are built to track and manipulate the DOM and node values. They make quick work of updating the DOM and Interpolating values, but that means they have to track all the things.

These frameworks are designed to have as little HTML on the page as possible. This means they can spend more resources 'watching', poised to render the desired view and swap the HTML out as quickly as possible when something needs to look different.

This is not a literal example but imagine that the framework  puts a listener on every element in the DOM. There is a measurable resource load difference just rendering 500 elements without listeners, now render 500 elements and apply 500 listeners ... ask an Angular developer what happens when you hit 1k watched elements.

Granted this may not apply to your app. But you can imagine how ng-including every tool tip could get out of hand fast. Especially if it was user controlled content or a table getting populated without pagination.

That is a long way of saying ... you should have as many `<li>`'s as you want, but there should be ONE tooltip component. The 'state' of the tooltip should be managed through props passed to it in any number of ways. You can do it with data- but most likely since its Angular you should be passing the aria-hidden state, unique ID, its display: state and its content (the innerHTML) using Angular components.

Also, you will have to test and manage the focus. Depending on how the person’s screen reader is setup or how they use it, they will be navigating using named Elements so it’s possible they will skip right over things you want read because of the nesting structure you use. You can manage this with aria and role attributes to make sure the screen reader lands on the correct elements to trigger the intended code.

ie. they hit your `<li>` because its a named element, it reads "12345" because that's the first node value it finds ... but the tooltip is not triggered until you reach the  which is nesting the tip itself. The order of operations should be that the `<li>` which is most likely to be picked up on any screen reader setup is aria-labledby the  that wraps the tool tip. Same concept as a `<label for="">`.

For the full scoop on Aria Roles and scope management see - https://www.levelaccess.com/how-not-to-misuse-aria-states-properties-and-roles/

I put together a snippet of what your code would render if the list had multiple values. Read the following HTML out loud, each element ...

```
<ul>
  <li>
    12345
    <span aria-labelledby="number-tooltip">
      <div>
        <div id="number-tooltip" role="tooltip">
          This is a number
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    some string
    <span aria-labelledby="string-tooltip">
      <div>
        <div id="string-tooltip" role="tooltip">
          This is a string
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    some string
    <span aria-labelledby="string-tooltip">
      <div>
        <div id="string-tooltip" role="tooltip">
          This is a string
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    some string
    <span aria-labelledby="string-tooltip">
      <div>
        <div id="string-tooltip" role="tooltip">
          This is a string
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    some string
    <span aria-labelledby="string-tooltip">
      <div>
        <div id="string-tooltip" role="tooltip">
          This is a string
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Couldn't get through it right? Imagine that’s how you browsed the internet. Now because of Aria its much better, but if it’s not implemented correctly and tested from a Usability perspective you can wind up inadvertently serving a user that exact experience.

This all sounds like a lot of work. It is, but once you do it the first time it’s way faster the second. Read through the tooltip tutorial above and transpose those concepts into your Angular tool tips and you will have actually solved a human interaction hurdle as well as appeased your Aria QA checklist.